# Sincerely wants to have Emunah?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim

What would you tell someone who tells you that they sincerely want to have emunah but is having a hard time believing in things such as Torah miSinai, the special "chosen" status of the Children of Israel, belief in Hashem, as well as other fundamental principles of our religion?

Comment: This question is a little too open-ended IMO. Could you be more specific about what the issues with these concepts are?

Comment: Believe in hashgacha pratit.